# How to escape percent symbol in path (batch script)

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping

This is my script. I tried many ways, but can't escape % symbol.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL DisableDELAYEDEXPANSION
CHCP 65001 >NUL

:start
set Input="C:\Transcode\ABC! code's 30% Special"
set Output="C:\Batch Script\DST&2"

REM set /p Input="Enter source folder link: "
REM set /p Output="Enter destination folder link: "  

set "SRC=%Input:"=%"
set "DST=%Output:"=%"

FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('DIR /b /s /a-d "%SRC%"') DO (
    call :mklink "%%a" "%%~na" "%%~xa" "%DST%"
)
Goto :EOF

   :mklink
    Set "FILENAME=%~2"
    Set "FILENAME=%FILENAME: =_%"
    Set "FILENAME=%FILENAME:-=_%"
    for %%b in ("%FILENAME:_=" "%") do (
        Echo %%b | FindStr /IRC:"wjpg" >Nul && (
            IF exist "%~4\ABC\%%~b%~3" del "%~4\ABC\%%~b%~3"
            ECHO mklink "%~4\ABC\%%~b%~3" "%~1" >> "%~4\log.txt" 2>&1
            mklink "%~4\ABC\%%~b%~3" "%~1"
        )
    )
    Goto :EOF
```

Attention: path can not change (don't add or remove character)

Comment: Didn't you try the answer I posted? What do you mean by "path"? Are you calling "Input" a "path"? The word "path" occurs nowhere in your script. You don't appear to be doing anything with the PATH system variable. This question needs more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

In a regular Windows batch file, you can escape a `%` in a string by using two of them:

```
set "Input=C:\Transcode\ABC! code's 30%% Special"
```

If you need double quotes as part of the string, then include them when referencing the variable: `"%Input%"`.

Comment: I would suggest the recommended syntax, `Set "Input=C:\Transcode\ABC! code's 30%% Special"`, then use `"%Input%"` where double-quoting is necessary.

Comment: @Compo yes, agreed.